# TS6 and TS3 meaning on FD's?

Tags: shifting, derailleur-front

I see these on the product model number of derailleurs but cant seem to know what's the difference? Like there would be 2 models for an alivio top swing fd and one would have the ts3 and the other would have the ts6 indication? I have seen this also on other variants like altus, acera, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe TS means Top Swing and the digit refers the chain stay angle range (3 for 63-66 degrees or 6 for 66-69 degrees).
For example, see the data for the FD-T4000-TS6 here:
https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-t4000/FD-T4000-TS6.html
and for the FD-T4000-TS3 here:
https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-t4000/FD-T4000-TS3.html